# how to set ajax.beginform sync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

**The Objective**

I would like to know if there's a way to set that Ajax.beginform sync ?? or if i'll have to use another type of form.

**The code:**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("InputMaterial", "Grid", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId ="divCurrentZone" ,
                                                                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                                                 HttpMethod = "POST" })) {
    <div id="divCurrentZone">
        @Html.Partial("_CurrentZone", Model)
    </div> 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean making the AJAX request synchronous? This usually isn't a good idea--what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Andrew!Yes, I'm trying to avoid multiple requests in case that user press 20 times the submit button

Comment: You should probably disable the "Submit" button once it's pressed, and re-enable it once the request successfully comes back.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that.. with OnBegin and OnSuccess.. :( I thought that maybe there's a better choice, Ty!